# Describing features that are included in a service

Tags: grammatical-number

When writing about more than one feature. Would you write

"The service *includes* features such as A, B and C"

or

"The service *include* features such as A, B and C"

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is correct. *The service* is singular, so the third-person singular *includes* form of the verb is required. If you were to write *the services*, then *include* would be correct.